# Show & Hide Webbrowser in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

In my C# win app , i have a web browser navigating to my own application form.
This application form is having 3 pages.I don't want to show the first pages . But still need to choose values from first page and click submit button so that it will take the values to second page and so on.i achieve this process too.

Now my problem is i cant hide those first two pages.

After showing two pages its navigating to third page.

My Code

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://test.com/page1.aspx");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {

            var sub = webBrowser1.Document.All["submit"];
            var ele = webBrowser1.Document.All["biz_type"];

            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("biz_type") != null)
            {
                  HtmlElement selectF8 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("biz_type");

                foreach (HtmlElement item in selectF8.Children)
                {
                    if (item.InnerText == "First")
                    {
                        item.SetAttribute("Selected", "Selected");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id") != null)
            {

                HtmlElement selectF8 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id");
                var newOption = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("option");
                newOption.InnerText = "Shop Name";

                newOption.SetAttribute("value", "12345");
                newOption.SetAttribute("Selected", "Selected");
                selectF8.AppendChild(newOption);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
            }

 //Code for second page
            var email = webBrowser1.Document.All["email"];
            var ref = webBrowser1.Document.All["ref"];

            email.InnerText = "test@gmail.com";

            ref.InnerText = "1222";

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");


       };
```

Comment: how exactly you want to "hide"? like show a blank page instead? or hide the webbrowser itself?

Comment: i want to hide webbroser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can layout a browser at new form, and add the following code at Init.

```
this.SuspendLayout();
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```